# Powering flash light directly from battery

Tags: batteries, lamp

I have Bowens 500R studio lamp (http://www.bowensdirect.com/gemini500r)
It can be powered from a 12V battery (there is a 15 din input at the back of the unit) through a Travel Pack (http://www.bowensdirect.com/travelpak-small-and-bag).

The Travel Pack uses a 12V SLA battery.

I would like to build a custom DIY battery pack that uses a larger capacity battery.

Can I connect the battery directly to the flash?
Is there anything 'magic' that the Travel Pack control unit does wrt the current? It has a charge indicator and a slot for a charger, but I don't need them. I can charge the battery using car battery charger.

I saw a lot of DIY battery packs that use an expensive pure sine inverter to convert 12V DC to 220V AC and connect the flash unit using mains cable.

But since the unit has a battery input that I presume accepts 12V is there anything stopping me from connecting the battery directly?

Comment: I have no way of knowing for sure but given the 15-pin connector, I'd bet the pack isn't simply supplying 12 volts. They may have designed the flash to only use their pack, to force you to buy it. Also, even if it does take just 12 volts, you probably have no easy way to figure out the connection to the 15-pin connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Travelpack manual:-

> Q. I hear a whistling noise when the unit is charging. Is my Travelpak
>   developing a fault?
>
> A. No, the harder the Travelpak has to work the more obvious this will
>   become. This will be more apparent when the unit is set to fast charge
>   and the battery has a low power charge remaining.

This suggests that the TravelPack has an inverter which generates high voltage to charge the flash capacitor. When mains power is used the flash unit probably just rectifies it to produce a high voltage directly, and so does not need an inverter (unlike battery powered flash units).

You could hook a larger battery up to the Travelpack, but connecting the battery directly to the flash won't work.